# Pandas - How to convert a dataframe to a new datatype but ignore the header/first row

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a data frame to type float so I can do some calculations with it. However I have a header/first row which has strings in so when i try to convert it to float it comes up with this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'column1'
```

I have tried:

```
file_float = file.astype(float)
```

And have tried converting the columns seperatly:

```
file['column1'] = file.column1.astype(float)
file['column2'] = file.column2.astype(float)
```

However they both have the same error. So i need a way of converting the columns to type float and ignoring the first row as it contains column1 and column2 so cant be converted to a float.
Thanks

Comment: How is created `DataFrame` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is of type int, a really dumb way to do this is

```
file_float = file + 0.0
```

Comment: My data frame is currently type string but need to converted it to float, will this work?

Comment: I have tried this but still get the same error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'column1'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is your data numbers in string form, e.g. "45" (as opposed to 45)?

Comment: Yes, I need to bypass the first row as it cant convert column1 to a float. i think

Comment: Try doing it columnwise, e.g. file['column1'] = file.column1 + 0.0

Comment: This still doesn't work, it might be because when I try to do to a calculation on the values inside the column, it starts with column1 which it cant do any caluclations on as it is not a number. I think i have to find away to just ignore the first row @Ketil Tveiten

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I thought you were somehow getting the column header mixed up in your data, as opposed to having a "wrong" row in there. Wald's answer is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, you have a dataframe full of numbers except for the first row which contains strings. There are several ways to remedy this. In the first place, you could read the data in differently when you do for example by using the `header` or `skiprows` arguments in `pd.read_csv` or whatever you use to read in the data.

But looking at the situation you are in now, here is what you could do. I created a mini example dataframe (you should also do this the next time you ask a question as it helps people who answer).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['header1', 2, 3], 'col2':['header2', 5, 6]})

      col1     col2
0  header1  header2
1        2        5
2        3        6
```

I think you might want to keep the header as the name of the columns. If you don't, skip the next code snippet.

```
df.columns = df.iloc[:1].values.tolist()[0]

   header1  header2
0  header1  header2
1        2        5
2        3        6
```

Finally there are two ways to get rid of the row. Either one should work (don't use both, you would lose two rows):

```
df.drop(df.head(1).index, inplace=True)
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

Now you can use convert the dataframe to floats:

```
df = df.astype(float)

   header1  header2
1      2.0      5.0
2      3.0      6.0
```

**Edit:**
If the problem is not the first row (but some unkown row with strings), try this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='force')
```

Finally to get rid of missing values (which are created where the strings were) you could do this:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify header=None without reading it in. As my dataframe is created in the code could you do something like :                           
           file_no_header = file(header=None)

Comment: @Harry Maguire if the code generates the dataframe, you could adjust the generation process to not create a header. But I can't help you on that without seing what you are doing. Also, what exactly is the error that you get when running my code?

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'column1'

Comment: @Harry Maguire you described it in a way that made me think the first row was the problem. That doesn't seem to be the case. I edited my answer for a way to get rid of all strings in all columns. Note that you may lose some entries.

Comment: Im sorry but i still get the same error    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'column1'

Comment: I feel like we are not on the same page here. Have you tried the edit solution? In the case of your dataframe it would be `for col in file.columns: file[col] = pd.to_numeric(file[col], errors='force')` It certainly works everytime I try it with an example. Can you let me see what your dataframe looks like?

Comment: The data frame has 3 columns. But only has 2 headers. The first column which has no header is a sort of index and is not useful. Should i just delete this column? And if so how?

Comment: I have managed to get the code to run by saving the dataframe as a csv and the calling it in like this: file.to_csv('file.csv') df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=',', header=None) But this is long

Comment: You can get rid of the column by using `file.drop(columns=['column_name'], inplace=True)` with `column_name` the name of the column that you want to drop. But this is getting off-topic. I'm afraid, I cannot help you. I just can't think of reason why the `pd.to_numeric` wouldn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by using bracket notation.

Meaning, if my dataframe's 0th row (first row) contains the headers and I want to cast all the values but preserve/ignore the header, id do:

`file['column_1'][1:] = file['column_3'][1:].astype(float)`

The `[1:]` skips the 0th / first row.

Hope that helps!